# PHP Mysql Select multiple table, and make multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, model

I have 4 tables.

student (id_student, name)

subject (id_subject, subject_name)

subject_category (id_subject_category, id_subject, subject_category)

score (id_score, id_student, id_subject, id_subject_category, score)

```
public function score(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('student');
    $query0 = $this->db->get();
    $data=$query0->result_array();
    $j = 0;


    while($j<count($data)){ 
        $sql2= "SELECT * FROM score where score.id_student = ?";  
        $data2 = $this->db->query($sql2,$data[$j]['id_student']);        
        $data2 =  $data2->result_array();
        $data[$j]['score'] = $data2;
        $j++;
        }
    return $data;  
}
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [final] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => John
                    [score] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_score] => 1
                                    [id_student] => 1
                                    [id_subject] => 2
                                    [id_subject_category] => 1
                                    [score] => 90
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_score] => 2
                                    [id_student] => 1
                                    [id_subject] => 2
                                    [id_subject_category] => 2
                                    [score] => 70
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_score] => 3
                                    [id_student] => 1
                                    [id_subject] => 2
                                    [id_subject_category] => 3
                                    [score] => 60
                                )


                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to make array like this

```
Array
(
    [final] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => John
                    [score] => Array
                        (
                            [id_subject] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                           [id_score] => 1
                                           [id_student] => 1
                                           [id_subject_category] => 1
                                           [score] => 90
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                           [id_score] => 2
                                           [id_student] => 1
                                           [id_subject_category] => 2
                                           [score] => 70
                                        )
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                           [id_score] => 3
                                           [id_student] => 1
                                           [id_subject_category] => 3
                                           [score] => 60
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: whats the difference between those i think just the keys right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function score(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('student');
$query0 = $this->db->get();
$data=$query0->result_array();
$j = 0;


while($j<count($data)){ 
    $sql2= "SELECT * FROM score where score.id_student = ?";  
    $data2 = $this->db->query($sql2,$data[$j]['id_student']);        
    $data2 =  $data2->result_array();
    $data[$j]['score'][$data[$j]['id_student']] = $data2;
    $j++;
    }
return $data;  
}
```